Copying from Neovim to System Clipboard causes a newline character at the end of line
I want to copy the line from neovim to the  system clipboard (using "+yy command) but it adds a newline character to the end (two lines are seen in gedit).


Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04

Count your newlines, it works out. There's one newline at the end of your line which you copy. There's one newline in your "empty" gedit file. Makes two in total. If you don't want to copy the newline, don't.

That is expected behavior and not a bug. What you want to do is manually yank the entire line by

Going in front of the line with ^ or 0 depending on the use case
Start system clipboard copy with "+y
Do g_ to select the entire line without the last newline character(\n)

The final command will look like 0 "+yg_
